# Is 260 picoampere current sufficient to transmit a signal through a 1 micron diameter wire?

Tags: electrical-engineering

This is a question about scale. A normal household runs on 100 ampere, a lightbulb on 1 ampere. Nanoampere is a billion times less, picoampere a trillion times less. When building machines at the micron scale, are amperages in the nano- or pico-scale useful? More specifically, can 260 picoampere be used to transmit a signal through a 1 micron wire?

The context to the question is this hypothesis: https://www.docdroid.net/QzUS2FM/the-reverse-of-photosynthesis-as-a-source-for-electric-currents-in-neurons-pdf

Comment: If you put 260 pA in one end of the wire you'll get 260 pA out of the other if you don't burn it up. Whether it will burn up or not will depend on the temperature where power dissipated in the conductor equals heat lost to surroundings.

Answer (score 0):

The resistance of a wire goes up as its area goes down, and it goes up as the length goes up.  You didn't say how long your hypothetical wire would be.  Let's say it's 100 microns long.  Then according to [this handy calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wire-resistance) resistance would be 1.68 ohms. So a 260 pA current would correspond to a voltage drop of 436 pV.  I don't think 436 pV is all that useful.  Most modern electronics (which BTW are built internally to nanometer scale, even smaller than your micron scale), operate on the order of say 3 volts.

Comment: If wire parameters are unchanged (conductance, diameter), will 260 pA get signal as far as 130 pA going as far as it can, then "boosting" signal with 130 pA? (does that scale linearly?)

Comment: Resistance scales linearly with length. So for length L, L/2 == R/2. Voltage is I*R. Amperage is split in two, one half of electrons at beginning, and a second half boosted in after L/2. Voltage for first half becomes I/2*R/2 = V/4, one fourth? Does that double ability of signal to propagate the same length with the same amount of electrons?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comments.  I think you may have some misunderstanding about how electricity works.  I'd suggest you get some textbooks and read up on the basics.  Or maybe start with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law